# Вместо суммирования Pandas соединяет значения в одну строку

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Коллеги, подскажите пожалуйста:
1. Прочёл .csv (разделитель точка с запятой). Приходится играться с кодировкой, так как есть русский текст
2. Сгруппировал и просуммировал
3. Вместо суммы получаю конкатенацию

Вопрос: вместо конкатенации нужна нормальная сумма (.csv = https://transfiles.ru/kq9g5), (.xlsx = https://transfiles.ru/5t38n)

Listing:

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
import csv
import codecs
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('C:\py3\Test1\Test2.csv', sep=';', encoding = "866")
df.head(10)
#Создаём файл Pivot.xlsx
df1 = df.groupby('Global Dimension 2 Code')['Amount'].sum()
df1.to_csv('C:\py3\Test1\Pivot.csv')
df11 = pd.read_csv('C:\py3\Test1\Pivot.csv')
w11 = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\py3\Test1\Pivot.xlsx')
df11.to_excel(w11, sheet_name='Pivot', index=False, engine='xlsxwriter')
w11.save()
```

Comment: можете выложить CSV на какой-нибудь файлообменник и привести в ответе пример выходного DataFrame'а?

Comment: Добавлена ссылка на .csv

Comment: Раз конкатенация, значит опознается как строки. Нужно конвертировать в числа.

Comment: Согласен. Вот только не знаю как. Если подскажете, то было бы супер. Пытался, но надо не всю строку, а только значения из столбца "Amount"

Comment: Огромное спасибо, MaxU! Просьба ещё помочь со следующим: 1. Добавлена ссылка на .xlsx; Вопросы: а. почему первая строка отличается от тех что идут ниже неё (нужно, чтобы 1-я строка была такой же как все остальные); b. Почему не просуммировались пустые (нужно чтобы и пустые просуммировались)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Столбец `Amount` воспринимается как строка, т.к. по умолчанию в качестве разделителя целой и дробной части используется точка (`'.'`), а ваших данных использована запятая (`','`).

Укажите `decimal=','` явно:

```
In [18]: df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\download\Test2.csv', sep=';', decimal=',')
#  NOTE:  ------------------------------------------------>  ^^^^^^^^^^^

In [19]: df.groupby('Global Dimension 2 Code', as_index=False)['Amount'].sum()
Out[19]:
  Global Dimension 2 Code    Amount
0                     L01 -32338.00
1                     L02  -3619.59
2                     L03  -1268.08
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [28]: (df.assign(Global_Dimension_2_Code=df['Global Dimension 2 Code'].fillna('EmptyAmount'))
            .groupby('Global_Dimension_2_Code', as_index=False)
            ['Amount'].sum())
Out[28]:
  Global_Dimension_2_Code    Amount
0             EmptyAmount -24646.81
1                     L01 -32338.00
2                     L02  -3619.59
3                     L03  -1268.08
```

**UPDATE2:**

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\download\Test2.csv', sep=';', decimal=',')
res = (df.assign(Global_Dimension_2_Code=df['Global Dimension 2 Code'].fillna('EmptyAmount'))
         .groupby('Global_Dimension_2_Code', as_index=False)
         ['Amount'].sum())
res.to_excel(r'c:\temp\result.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Нужна ещё помощь: а. почему первая строка отличается от тех что идут ниже неё (нужно, чтобы 1-я строка была такой же как все остальные); b. Почему не просуммировались пустые (нужно чтобы и пустые просуммировались)?

Comment: @2b4fITin, как должна называться пустая категория?

Comment: Пусть называется EmptyAmount

Comment: @2b4fITin, не совсем понял первый вопрос - вы имеете ввиду наименования столбцов?

Comment: Вы уже на него ответили MaxU, добавив в коде as_index=False. Я уже посмотрел -))

Comment: Имел наглость добавить encoding = "866", error_bad_lines=False и не присваивается EmptyAmount. В отработке .xlsx нету строки "0             EmptyAmount -24646.81"

Comment: Отклоните там правку, мышь скользнула, не ту пипу кликнул.

Comment: Мне отклонить? или MaxU?

Comment: То есть нужно в первоначальный .csv в пустые поля по столбцу Amount вписать EmptyAmount, а потом просуммировать по EmptyAmount и вывести в Pivot.xlsx вместе с не пустыми строками

Comment: @0xdb, отклонил :)

Comment: @2b4fITin, как то у вас сложно ;-) Попробуйте решение из `UPDATE2`

Comment: Да -)) Есть такое. Если честно, то в получаемом мною массиве много ошибок, одна из которых это сдвиг внутри строки (например на 2 поля вправо, а где-то на 3 поля, а где-то на одно поле). И поэтому в столбце Amount возникают пустые поля... Кароче в идеале надо находить эти строки со сдвигом внутри, потом определять сдвиг и сдвигать обратно. Таким образом на выходе должен образоваться "причёсанный" массив данных, который уже можно крутить-вертеть... Ну а пока вот так вот пытаюсь что-то придумать и сварить кашу из топора. -)

Comment: В любом случае огромное спасибо за помощь! -))

Comment: @2b4fITin, всегда рад помочь! :) По поводу поломанных данных - попробуйте создать небольшой __воспроизводимый__ пример данных и открыть новый SO вопрос с этими воспроизводимыми данными, тогда можно будет попытаться найти подходящее решение

Comment: Да. Спасибо. Я уже тоже подумал об этом. Подготовлю и создам новый вопрос